# Initialize an object with a block

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to initialize an object with a block as follows?

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar,:baz
  def initialize(bar,baz)
    @bar, @baz = bar, baz
  end
end

Foo.new do |bar, baz|
  # some logic to be implemented
  # @bar, @baz to be assigned
end
```

Comment: Sure, but don't forget to provide the arguments. And the block won't do anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Of course, you can `yield` from within `initialize`, there's nothing special about it:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
  def initialize
    yield self
  end
end

Foo.new do |f|
  f.bar = 123
  f.baz = 456
end
#=> <Foo:0x007fed8287b3c0 @bar=123, @baz=456>
```

You could also evaluate the block in the context of the receiver using [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

Foo.new do
  @bar = 123
  @baz = 456
end
#=> #<Foo:0x007fdd0b1ef4c0 @bar=123, @baz=456>
```

Comment: What if I want an object could be instantiated in both ways: with a block and with constructor?

Comment: @DreamWalker you can make the arguments optional and only yield if [`block_given?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F).

Answer (score 8):

If the constructor's arguments are optional and the same attributes are writable, you can achieve something similar with [tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-tap). `tap` is especially nice when you need to set instance values that are not set by the constructor.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar,:baz
  def initialize(bar: nil, baz: nil)
    @bar, @baz = bar, baz
  end
end

foo1 = Foo.new(bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz')
foo2 = Foo.new.tap do |f|
  f.bar = 'bar'
  f.baz = 'baz'
end
```