# Ruby object initialization using instance_eval

Tags: ruby, initialization, block

Consider the following class:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :first_name

    def initialize(&block)
        instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
    end
end
```

When I create an instance of Person as follows:

```
person = Person.new do
    first_name = "Adam"
end
```

I expected the following:

```
puts person.first_name
```

to output "Adam".  Instead, it outputs only a blank line: the first_name attribute has ended up with a value of nil.

When I create a person likes this, though:

```
person = Person.new do
    @first_name = "Adam"
end
```

The first_name attribute is set to the expected value.

The problem is that I want to use the attr_accessor in the initialization block, and not the attributes directly.  Can this be done?

Comment: Use `self.first_name=`. It will use the accessor. `first_name = ` sets a local variable with that name.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that point for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby setters cannot be called without an explicit receiver since local variables take a precedence over method calls.

You don’t need to experiment with such an overcomplicated example, the below won’t work as well:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def set_name(new_name)
    name = new_name
  end
end
```

only this will:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def set_name(new_name)
    # name = new_name does not call `#name=`
    self.name = new_name
  end
end
```

---

For your example, you must explicitly call the method on a receiver:

```
person = Person.new do
  self.first_name = "Adam"
end
```

Comment: Please don't tell me what to experiment on. I  am providing a simple example so that the issue isn't hard to see.  That is, I want to call accessors from an initialization block.  Can you tell me how to do this or not?

Comment: I did explain it in the original version of the answer, but since you did not seem to understand the explanation, I put the exact code for your case as well.

Comment: Thank you.  Your edit was made after my comment.  Check the timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

If the code is run with warnings enabled (that is `ruby -w yourprogram.rb`)
it responds with : "warning: assigned but unused variable - first_name", with a line-number pointing to `first_name = "Adam"`. So Ruby interprets `first_name` as a variable, not as a method. As others have said, use an explicit reciever: `self.first_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
person = Person.new do |obj|
  obj.first_name = "Adam"
end

puts person.first_name
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to do this without the block parameter.

Comment: You will have to pass argument to the block to get it executed.

Comment: The block is being executed.  I know this because - although it is not included in the above example - when I remove the accessor, I get a method missing error when the block is executed.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065817/initialize-an-object-with-a-block

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the attr_accessor in the initialization block, and not the attributes directly

`instance_eval` undermines encapsulation. It gives the block access to instance variables and private methods.

Consider passing the person instance into the block instead:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name

  def initialize
    yield(self) if block_given?
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
adam = Person.new do |p|
  p.first_name = 'Adam'
end
#=> #<Person:0x00007fb46d093bb0 @first_name="Adam">
```

Comment: Thank you, but I understand that it instance_eval undermines encapsulation: that is not at issue here.

Comment: @Adam I see, I thought you meant _"I don't want the block to be able to set the attributes directly"_

Comment: I can see why you thought that.  I'm following my way through the book "Mastering Ruby Closures" and one of the examples uses blocks that invoke accessors instead of attributes.  Turns out, the author forgot to put in the "self" references, hence my confusion.  He does mention it in the errata, which I happened upon after reading the answer given by mudasobwa!