# Ruby Class Output

Tags: ruby, class

I am trying my hands at Ruby, below is the code that I am writing in 2 different ways to understand Ruby Classes. In first block I am using accessor method (combination of accessor read & write) and I want to print final line as "lord of the rings is written by Tolkien and has 400 pages". How can I make that happen? I understand that adding string and integer will throw an error. I can get them to print on separate lines, its just that I can't get them in a sentence.

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author, :pages
end

book1 = Book.new()
book1.title = 'lord of the rings'
book1.author = 'Tolkien'
book1.pages = 400

puts book1.title
puts book1.author
puts book1.pages

#puts book1.title + " is written by " + book1.author + " and has " + book1.pages + " pages" <<<this errors out for known reason>>>
```

Second piece of code doing the same thing but I am using instance variable and have figured out how to get desired output. However, please advise if there's a better way of doing this?

```
class Novel
  def initialize(title, author, pages)
    @title = title
    @author = author
    @pages = pages
  end

  def inspect
    "#{@title} is written by #{@author} and has #{@pages} pages"
  end
end

novel1 = Novel.new('harry potter', 'JK Rowling', 300)
puts novel1.inspect
```

Comment: Both "styles" have their place, depending on what you want to achieve exactly. It's not an either-or kind of situation. Note though that the methods generated with `attr_accessor` also set instance variables internally.

Comment: Or also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34065817/5239030

Comment: You would normally initialize the values of the three instance variables as you have in #2, If you need to "get" the values of those those variables from outside the class you need a *getter method* for each (e.g., `def title; @title; end`), which, for convenience, `attr_reader` will construct. for you. If you need to "set" the values of those those variables from outside the class you need  *setter methods* (e.g., `def title=(val); @title=val; end`), which `attr_writer` will construct. If you need to do both, use `attr_accessor`, which amounts to your #1 and #2 combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you are providing access the info you want and leaving it up to the client to format the output.  For example you could have gotten what you wanted by adding this line in place of your commented line.

```
puts "#{book1.title} is written by #{book1.author} and has #{book1.pages} pages"
```

In your second example you are "pushing" that code down into the Novel class and proving a method to produce the output you want.  BTW,  don't use `inspect` as a method name, [inspect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is already a defined method

For example the following will print the same info twice.

```
class Novel
  attr_accessor :title, :author, :pages  
  def initialize(title, author, pages)
    @title = title
    @author = author
    @pages = pages
  end

  def info
    "#{@title} is written by #{@author} and has #{@pages} pages"
  end
end

novel = Novel.new('harry potter', 'JK Rowling', 300)
puts novel.info
puts "#{novel.title} is written by #{novel.author} and has #{novel.pages} pages"
```