# Why would you call `super` with a block in the initialize method of a class inherting from Module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

When inheriting from `Module` you can pass a block to `super()` and it is executed:

```
class Foo < Module
  def initialize
    super() do
      # do some other stuff...
    end
  end
end
```

Why would you use this over just calling `super()`, without the block, followed by the rest of the code, such as:

```
class Foo < Module
  def initialize
    super()
    # do some other stuff...
  end
end
```

An less contrived example would be:

```
class QuestionAttr < Module
  def initialize(method_name)
    super() do
      define_method "#{method_name}?" do
        !!public_send(method_name)
      end
    end
  end
end

Fruit = Struct.new(:colour) do
  include QuestionAttr.new(:colour)
end

fruit = Fruit.new('red')
fruit.colour? # => true
```

Why would I `define_method` inside the block passed to `super()`, as per the above example, instead of omitting the block passed to `super()` and `define_method` afterwards.

Comment: As a side note when inhering from `Class` the block passed to `super()` is not executed and silently ignored.

Comment: How do you inherit from `Class` when Ruby prohibits inheriting from `Class` or singleton classes?

Comment: Perhaps the parent class/module has been set up like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065817/initialize-an-object-with-a-block).

Comment: @pjs: That's right, here `super` calls [`Module#initialize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-new) which evaluates a given block in the module's context. The question - as I've understood it - however is why you would make use of that in this case, not why does it work.

Comment: @cremno The problem is there's not really a "this case" to discuss, since the example doesn't give any context.  I was trying to point to a specific use case that would justify this approach.

Comment: @pjs: Agreed. A non-contrived example would be more helpful.

Comment: @cremno Even a contrived example, if there's some actual working code.

Comment: @Kris Do you have access to, and can you show, what the inherited module/class `initialize` method looks like?

Comment: @cremno by "inheriting from Class" I mean `class Foo; end;Foo.class # => Class`

Comment: @pjs I've added a less contrived example.

Comment: Maybe, since a block can be passed to `Module#new` and it is executed in the context of the module, i.e. `Module.new { }`, then that is all I am doing here when calling `super() { }`. It just isn't need, I am already within this context in the `#initialize` method, thus calling `super()` with a block or not, as the same effect in this case.

Comment: Why would you create a class that inherits from `Module` and not just define a `Module` straightaway? #confused Is there a specific pattern/code-sample you are inspired by?

Comment: @nathanvda Because you can pass parameters (state) in to the module and use that to dynamically create methods based on those parameters. It is a rare technique and there are other options like defining class methods (aka macros) which when called will then define new methods on the target class, e.g. `has_many` in Rails. Here is an article on the technique: https://solnic.codes/2012/08/13/subclassing-module-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Insert *mind blown* gif :) :) Very interesting technique, and learned something new today :clap: :clap:

Comment: Kris, I was going to ask you for a link to where you saw that construct, but I see you have in your last comment. Thanks. It was an interesting read. You might consider editing your question to provide more context for the potential use of subclasses of `Module`.